# Error of a field on the buildForm in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

```php
/**
     * ¨Allows you to have the basic configuration of a form field!
     * 
     * @param string $label
     * @param string $placeholder
     * @return array
     */
    private function getConfiguration($label, $placeholder){
        return [
            'label' => $label,
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => $placeholder
            ]
        ];
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Titre", "Tapez ici le titre de votre nouvelle annonce !") )
            ->add('slug',TextType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Chaine Url", "Adresse Url (automatique)") )
            ->add('coverImage', UrlType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Url de l'image principale", "Donnez l'adresse de l'image qui donne vraiment envie"))
            ->add('introduction', TextType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Introduction", "Donnez une description global de votre appartement"))
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Description détaillée", "Tapez une description qui donne vraiment envie de venir chez vous !"))
            ->add('rooms', IntegerType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Nombre de chambre", "Indiquez ici le nombre de chambresdisponnibles"))
            ->add('price', MoneyType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Prix par nuit", "Indiquez le prix que vous voulez !"))
        ;
    }
```

This picture shows the rendered view.

Why does the *`Description détaillée`* field not appear?

[image]

Comment: Does the Symfony profiler show any errors related to the field?

Comment: How do you render the form? It might help if you show us the template.

Comment: the symfony profiler does not display an error

Comment: the code for creating the form creation is already above, I wanted to create a form which contains the following fields, title, slug, image, introduction, content, room and at the end the price. The airbnb model

Comment: It might be a jss/css error, as everything renders ok but that field, which is the only textarea. Check the console just in case.